# Deploy Sveltekit on own Windows/Linux Server?

Tags: deployment, web-hosting, sveltekit

I am almost done with my first Test Sveltekit Application and want deploy the App in the next Days in my private Network. When I google for this I get flooded with "Deploy to Vercel, Netlify.... and so on" but I dont see much for deploying it the Application to an Server.

Can somebody explain what to do? The Application uses Endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would likely want to run it through a Node server, for this you can use the `adapter-node` package, see the documentation for it for more information.

https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-node

Comment: Thanks man i will check this out